# Using extend_schema_field for custom field

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, django-serializer, drf-spectacular

I created a custom field named `PictureField` which creates thumbnails with uploaded images and I used it in my `User` model
**User model:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    profile_image = PictureField(make_thumbnail=True)
```

My `PictureField`, gets an image file like `django's ImageField` and returns a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "image": {
      "url": "string",
      "name": "string"
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "string",
      "name": "string"
    } | None
}
```

Everything is fine and my custom field works correct. my problem is the schema that created with drf_spectacular. I don't know how to set this output to my `PictureSerializerField`. already, I set `@extend_schema_field` decorator for my field to `BINARY` (for being able to upload file with Swagger) and with this, my Response output is set to "string":

```
@extend_schema_field(OpenApiTypes.BINARY)
class PictureSerializerField(ImageField):
     ...
```

Now, my Swagger docs look like this:[image]
I'm looking for something like below to show my output to Response and also I be able to upload file in Request:

```
@extend_schema_field({
    'request':OpenApiTypes.BINARY,
    'response': {}# My output example that I said above
})
```

my idea is creating an empty serializer class and set `@extend_schema_serializer` on that but I think it isn't good way and doesn't works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I've fixed it. just read a little OpenAPI documentation and also I saw `@extend_schema_field` supports `dict` parameter, so I write my code like this:

```
@extend_schema_field({'type':"string",'format':'binary',
    'example':{
             "image":{"url":"string","name":"string"},
             "thumbnail":{"url":"string","name":"string"}
    }
})
class PictureSerializerField(ImageField):
    ...
```

And it looks OK.[image]